# Restrict product variation to certain countries using Woocommerce

Tags: geolocation, woocommerce

I have products with 3,6,12,18 months product price variations.
I'd like to restrict the 3,6 month option only to specific countries.
Ideally this would happen by automatically geolocating the user.

How do I accomplish this with Woocommerce?